# Limitation of stoi, stol and stoll in convert string of largest size data type to int data type

Tags: c++, string, long-integer, unsigned-long-long-int

We know stoi, stol and stoll are used to convert string data type to int data type. But what if the number is itself greater than pow(2,64). Is there any way or built function to convert the largest string to a number?

Comment: What would be the point of converting it to a number if you can't store it? You would need a special type designed for massive values, such as [infint](https://github.com/sercantutar/infint) which can parse a `string`.